# TeamCity using git pull command line build step returns Git error: “Host Key Verification Failed” when connecting to remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm trying to setup TeamCity where I work, with a private repo hosted on github.

The project is a web app, so what I'm trying to do is that on every new commit on github that TeamCity checkout the new revision and update the working copy on our development server.

So, not only do the Agent Checkout but use a command line build step to do a git pull.

I've tried previously with https link but was getting Authentication failed or https://github.com is an invalid argument.

Now I've changed the URL to use ssh, but I keep getting

[image]

If I change the git URL to use https I keep getting

[image]

I've tried setting up the VCS to use ssh key but keep getting the access denied error.

Comment: Can I just clarify your current setup - you've got a VCS root already that triggers when a commit is made to Github. As part of the build steps, the first thing you want to do is also do a git pull to your dev server. Is that correct?

Comment: @DevOps As it turns out I had to copy the ssh key to the teamcity user folder and give it Read permissions. After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue.

The ssh key was created under my user folder on Windows Server.

I've copied it to the teamcity user and gave it read permissions and worked fine.